# Understanding the code execution path for given code

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I am new to Java, Can anyone explain me which method invokes the call method in below given code , 
also help me to understand the code execution path for give code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000);         
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Get ExecutorService from Executors utility class, thread pool size is 10
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);            
        List<Future<String>> list = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();            
        Callable<String> callable = new MyCallable();

        for(int i=0; i< 100; i++){              
            Future<String> future = executor.submit(callable);              
            list.add(future);
        }

        for(Future<String> fut : list){
            try {               
                System.out.println(new Date()+ "::"+fut.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are new to Java but want to work with `thread`s already? Maybe it's best if you understand the basics first and know how to debug an application before you are getting into advance stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code submits a `Callable` 100 times to an `ExecutorService` containing 10 threads and captures the Futures that indicate when each Callable has been run.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);            
List<Future<String>> list = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();            
Callable<String> callable = new MyCallable();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{              
  Future<String> future = executor.submit(callable);              
  list.add(future);
}
```

Once each of the 10 threads are running a Callable the remaining Callables will be queued up and are run as each thread becomes available.

After all the Callables have been added, the next block of code gets the result from each Future, the important thing being that the calling thread will block on the call to Future.get until the Callable finishes, so the results will be printed in the order the Callables were added.

```
for(Future<String> fut : list)
{
  try 
  {               
    System.out.println(new Date() + "::" + fut.get());
  } 
  catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) 
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Finally the executor is shutdown to kill the threads it contains.

```
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 1):

In this code you are using an Executor and a ThreadPool. `executor.submit(callable)` makes the the executor put your Callable into a thread in the pool and to start this thread by running the `call()` method. To understand this code you should read theese three sites:

Callable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

ThreadPool: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Executor: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Answer (score 0):

When `executor.sumbit(callable);` is called, an asynchronous task starts in parallel of the current thread to call the `call()` method of the provided `Callable`. "In parallel" means, here, in one of the 10 threads of the thread pool created by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);`.

Your current thread (in `main()`) then keeps going, doing this a hundred times (The `Callable`s are queued if all 10 threads are already busy).

To retrieve the result of each call, you then have to use the [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object that each of the `submit`s gave you, using `get()`. This `fut.get()` will wait until the corresponding `call()` is finished, and return the result of the call.